# RTTI - why is in some cases TTypedData.CompType nil?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a `TValue` enclosing a set. `TTypedData.CompType` is nil. So calling `TValue.ToString` throws an exception, because `System.TypInfo.SetToString` assumes `CompType` to never be nil.

Why is `CompType` nil for some set types?

```
TTestEnumType = (tstEnum1 = 1, tstEnum2 = 2, tstEnum3 = 3, tstEnum4 = 4, tstEnum5 = 5, tstEnum6 = 6, tstEnum7 = 7);
TTestEnumTypeSet = set of TTestEnumType;
TTestSetOfByte = set of Byte;
```

Above we have defined two set types: `TTestEnumTypeSet` and `TTestSetOfByte`.

The following simple test shows that `CompType` is nil for `TTestSetOfByte`.

```
procedure TTestUtlRttiComparer.TestSetToString;
var
  TypeData1: TTypeData;
  TypeData2: TTypeData;
  TypeInfo1: TTypeInfo;
  TypeInfo2: TTypeInfo;
begin
  TypeInfo1 := PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(TTestSetOfByte))^;
  TypeInfo2 := PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(TTestEnumTypeSet))^;
  CheckTrue(TypeInfo1.Kind = tkSet);
  CheckTrue(TypeInfo2.Kind = tkSet);

  TypeData1 := GetTypeData(@TypeInfo1)^;
  TypeData2 := GetTypeData(@TypeInfo2)^;
  CheckTrue(Assigned(TypeData1.CompType));
  CheckTrue(Assigned(TypeData2.CompType), 'TypeData2.CompType is NULL!!!! WHY??????'); // this FAILS!!!
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumerated types with explicitly assigned ordinality do not have RTTI. This is stated in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Enumerated_Types_with_Explicitly_Assigned_Ordinality):

> Enumerated constants without a specific value have RTTI:
>
> ```
> type SomeEnum = (e1, e2, e3);
> ```
>
> whereas enumerated constants with a specific value, such as the
>   following, do not have RTTI:
>
> ```
> type SomeEnum = (e1 = 1, e2 = 2, e3 = 3);
> ```

Comment: Wow that was fast! It'll be 8 mins before SO will even let me accept your answer. ;-)

Comment: Does {$M+}, still work to force RTTI in this case. Vague memory haven't done Delphi for a while...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No, there's simply no RTTI for these types ever.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan now I have run into a showstopper. The problem is that these enums with assigned ordinality have been around for ages. So modifying them would be quite a huge undertaking (testing especially).  Can you think of any way to obtain a TValue from a TRttiField or TRttiProperty that refers to such an enum?

Comment: Without any RTTI you are essentially stuck. Nothing much that you can do.